# Showing existence of a partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

How would one show that that $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=(0,0)$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ has second order partials but $f_{xy}(0,0) \neq f_{yx}(0,0)$.

I was thinking of just trying to directly compute or evaluate the difference quotients but this is really long and messy, is there a simpler way?

Comment: You have a quotient of polynomials. It is nondifferentiable only at points where the denominator is zero (in this case, $(0,0)$). Perhaps convince yourself of this fact.

Comment: As far as I can see we have here $\;f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=0\;$ . But you talk of seconds order derivatives, perhaps you meant $\;f''_{xy}\;$ or something like that?